# Probability household cars problem

Tags: probability

A survey consists of recording, the number of cars presently owned by a household among six major manufacturers. Order does not matter.

i.  Suppose that no household has more than four cars. In how many different ways can the survey sheet be filled out?

I was thinking maybe it would just be 4! + 6! but I have a feeling that is wrong, I'm not sure if that would account for multiple cars being from the same brand

Comment: It depends on what ways of filling out are to be considered different. Is a Toyota. a Toyota, and a Ford to be considered different from a Toyota, a Ford, and a Toyota?

Comment: @AndréNicolas no, order does not matter in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x_1$ be the number of GMs, let  $x_2$ the number of Fords, and so on up to $x_6$ being the number of Nissans. We want to find the number of solutions of 
$$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_6\le 4$$
in non-negative integers. This is the same as the number of solutions of 
$$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_6+x_7= 4$$
(the variable $x_7$ counts the number of empty slots in the four-car garage).

Now we have a standard *Stars and Bars* problem (please see Wikipedia). The number of solutions is $\binom{4+7-1}{7-1}$, that is, $\binom{10}{6}$, or equivalently $\binom{10}{4}$.

Comment: It is good to point out the fact that it is indeed possible for someone to own zero of the major brand cars (something which many people would overlook for this problem).  This answer correctly accounts for that small subtlety.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me, but I can't really see why the other answer of 6^n for n = 0 to 4 is wrong.  Can someone point out what is wrong with it that I dont see? @JMoravitz

Comment: @seanscal $\sum\limits_{n=0}^4 6^n$ answers the question of if the *order of the vehicles listed matters*.  (seen from multiplication principle).  This is however not the case, as the OP clarified, ToyotaToyotaFord is the *same* as ToyotaFordToyota, so you have overcounted.

Comment: ahhh ok, totally get it now, thanks a lot to both @JMoravitz and Andre!

Answer (score 1):

Look at the cases of different numbers of cars:

1. No cars: 1 way of filling out the survey
2. 1 car:   6 ways of filling out the survey.
3. 2 cars: 6*5/2 ways of filling out the survey without repetition;
           6 ways of filling out the survey with all the same manufacturer.
4. 3 cars: 6*5*4/(3*2*1) ways of filling out the survey without repetitions;
           6*5 ways of filling out the survey with 2 cars the same and 1 different;
           6 ways of filling out the survey with all the same manufacturer.
5. 4 cars: 6*5*4*3/(4*3*2*1) ways of filling out the survey without repetitions;
           6*5*4/2 ways of filling out the survey with 2 cars the same and the other 2 different (from each other and the first 2);
           6*5/2 ways of filling out the survey with 2 and 2;
           6*5 ways of filling out the survey with 3 cars the same and 1 different;
           6 ways of filling out the survey with all the cars from the same manufacturer.

Python has a built in module called itertools (https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) which has a iterator called combinations_with_replacement.

> import itertools as it
>
> tot = 0
>
> for r in range(5):
>
> ```
>  s=0
>
>  for i in it.combinations_with_replacement("ABCDEF",r):
>
>       s+=1
>
>  t+=s
>
>  print r,s,t
> ```
>
> 0    1    1
>   1    6    7
>   2   21   28
>   3   56   84
>   4  126  210

Total is 210

Comment: Stars and bars. How could I have forgotten. That's a much better way of doing it.